# how to display responses from a looped scrape (cheerio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, cheerio, scrape

I am scraping this site to collect all rows with the year 2013, but there are 7 pages and I have my request in a loop. How can I display the results after all 7 responses have been received? If I simply try to console.log the rowTrack array, it displays empty because of the async nature of the code. Ideally I want to run the requests in order of the loop so that the results of the first page are the first elements of the array etc..

```
var request = require("request"),
cheerio = require("cheerio"),
rowTrack = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {

var url = "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/alltime/world/?pagenum=" + i + "&p=.htm";
request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body),
            rows = $('table table tr');

        rows.each(function(j, element) {
            var select = $(element.children).text().split('\r\n')
            select.shift();
            select.pop();

            if (select[select.length - 1] == "2013") {

                rowTrack.push(select);

            }

        });
    }

});}
```

How can I display the results?

Answer (score 0):

The site you're scraping has changed a bit since the question was asked. The table is still there, but the URL and pagination are a bit different.

JS has moved on to promises and the `requests` package is deprecated. Nowadays, with promises, you'd do:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const baseUrl =
  "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/?area=XWW";
  
(async () => {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}&offset=${i * 100}`);
    const $ = cheerio.load(await response.text());
    results.push(...[...$("tr")]
      .map(e => [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text()))
      .filter(e => e.at(-1) === "2013")
    );
  }

  console.log(results);
})();
```

The above code runs in series, but you can parallelize it with `Promise.all`:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const baseUrl =
  "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/?area=XWW";

(async () => {
  const results = await Promise.all(
    [...Array(6)].map(async (_, i) => {
      const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}&offset=${i * 100}`);
      const $ = cheerio.load(await response.text());
      return [...$("tr")]
        .map(e => [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text()))
        .filter(e => e.at(-1) === "2013");
    })
  );

  console.log(results.flat());
})();
```

Node 18 has native fetch, but if you're stuck with a legacy situation without promises, you can store each result in an array and use a counter to determine how many requests have completed. When the last request resolves, trigger the next stage of processing.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const request = require("request"); // ^2.88.2

const getRankings = done => {
  const results = [];
  const total = 6;
  let completed = 0;
  const baseUrl =
    "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/?area=XWW";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    request(`${baseUrl}&offset=${i * 100}`, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.error(err);
      }
  
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      results[i] = [...$("tr")]
        .map(e => [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text()))
        .filter(e => e.at(-1) === "2013");
  
      if (++completed === total) {
        done(results.flat());
      }
    });
  }
};

getRankings(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

The above code runs all of the requests in parallel. To do the requests sequentially, you can chain the callbacks:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const request = require("request");

const getRankings = (done, results=[], total=6, i=0) => {
  const baseUrl =
    "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/?area=XWW";
  request(`${baseUrl}&offset=${i * 100}`, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);
    results[i] = [...$("tr")]
      .map(e => [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text()))
      .filter(e => e.at(-1) === "2013");
  
    if (i + 1 === total) {
      done(results.flat());
    }
    else {
      getRankings(done, results, total, i + 1);
    }
  });
}

getRankings(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Error handling on failed requests is left as an exercise. I haven't bothered adapting modern JS idioms like `.at(-1)`, `.flat()` and so forth to work on older Node versions. Cheerio's `.toArray()` can be used instead of spreads, `.at(-1)` can be recreated with roughly `const last = a => a[a.length-1];` and `.flat()` can be `[].concat(...results)`.